# How to set value in text view located inside Toolbar dynamically(Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

i have separate toolbar xml file.Below is our code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http:// schemas .android.com/ apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:id="@+id/showevents"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/cart"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/showevents"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/showevents"
        android:text="11"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

inside this i made one button and textview.i want to put value of text view from our activity class. my activity class is below:

```
public class ProductDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView productImage;
TextView productTitle,productPrice,productDescription,quantity,textOne;
Button addToCart,showevents;
NumberPicker numberPicker;
public static final String URLS ="http://192.168.1.8/wordpress/upmeapi/class-woocommerce.php?function=get_product_by_id_api";
RequestObject requestObject;
int count;
public static final String URLL = "http://192.168.1.8/wordpress/upmeapi/class-woocommerce.php?function=add_cart_api";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
  /*  final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);*/
    textOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textOne);
    showevents = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showevents);
    showevents.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductDetail.this,ViewCart.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    productImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ProductImageView);
    productTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ProductTitle);
    productPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ProductPrice);
    productDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ProductDetails);
    quantity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
    addToCart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddToCart);
    final long productId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong(
            "productId");

    System.out.println(productId);
    numberPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.TextQuantity);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(10);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            //Display the newly selected number from picker
           count = 0;
            count = newVal;

        }
    });

    addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                ProductHelper productHelper = new ProductHelper();
                productHelper.setProductId(productId);
                productHelper.setQuantity(count);
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String req = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productHelper);

                requestObject = ExceptionRequest.generateRequest(req);
                requestObject.setUrl(URLL);
                new AddToCartList().execute(requestObject);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


}
 private class AddToCartList extends AsyncTask<RequestObject, Void, JSONObject> {


    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(RequestObject... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(arg0[0], ServiceHandler.POST);

        //  List<Products> result = new ArrayList<Products>();

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        JSONObject product = new JSONObject();


        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                product = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rsBody");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return product;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {

            if (result!=null)
            {
                String status = result.getString("status");
                int totalCartItem = result.getInt("totalCartItem");
                textOne.setText(totalCartItem);
                Toast.makeText(ProductDetail.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;

       }
     }
 }
```

in our activity.xml file i include toolbar like this

```
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

But when i set the value in `textOne` variable i 'm getting error like   this

```
E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String       resource ID #0xa
      11-04 18:48:54.643 19770-19770/app.com.myfirstshoppingcart   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
    11-04 18:48:54.643 19770-19770/app.com.myfirstshoppingcart E/AndroidRuntime:       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
```

How can i set value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
int totalCartItem = result.getInt("totalCartItem");
textOne.setText(String.valueOf(totalCartItem));
```

Instead of

```
 int totalCartItem = result.getInt("totalCartItem");
 textOne.setText(totalCartItem);
```

[TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) has overridden method `setText(int resid)`, Which will try to get resource of specified integer. Result into `Resources$NotFoundException` if resource id not found.

Comment: @Anand Accept the answer if it helps you to resolve your problem.